# How to export print output as csv in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, ncdf4

I have a .nc file which contains time series data of 2010-2020 for a region. I want to export the time series in a .csv format. I am using following code in R to do the same. I am able to print the output. Could anyone please help me how can I export the output in csv.

```
library(ncdf4)
library(tidyverse)

setwd("D:/Test/")

our_nc_data <- nc_open("D:/Test/Data.nc")
print(our_nc_data)
attributes(our_nc_data$var)
attributes(our_nc_data$dim)

mnth <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "datamonth") #'datamonth' is the desired variable
nmnth <- dim(mnth)

data <- ncvar_get(our_nc_data, "Al")  #'Al' is the desired variable
ndata <- dim(data)

print(c(mnth, data))
```

The last line gives the output but as follows (a sample)

```
[1] 200601.00000 200602.00000 200603.00000 200604.00000 200605.00000 200606.00000 200607.00000 
200608.00000 200609.00000 200610.00000 200611.00000
[12] 200612.00000 200701.00000 200702.00000 200703.00000 200704.00000 200705.00000 
200706.00000 200707.00000 200708.00000 200709.00000 200710.00000
[23] 200711.00000 200712.00000 200801.00000 200802.00000 200803.00000 200804.00000 14.08254     
14.43839     14.57681     14.16317     15.02839     15.78833     15.37064
[34]     15.40193     14.82367     13.48399     15.12717     29.69734     40.03585     
35.27866     14.13794     14.27229     15.02839     15.78833
```

My desired output is a csv file in following format

```
mnth  data
200601  14.08254
200602  14.43839
200603  14.57681
```

How can I obtain this in R? Kindly help.

Comment: Is this just `write.csv(data.frame(mnth, data), "filename.csv")`?

Comment: Or `tibble(mnth, data) %>% write_csv("filename.csv")`, since the question is tagged `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 0):

try `write.csv(var_name, "file_name.csv")`

Comment: I tried it but it can export only one variable at one time. I want to export both variables together in same csv file.

Comment: combine them into a single data frame in R `bind_cols(mnth, data)` and then write the csv. you can use `bind_cols()` by installing the `tidyverse` packages or use base R with `cbind()`